# Discord Bot Kick Command Doesn't Work As Expected

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I need help with my kick command. I don't get any error,But the result is something else then what I expected,My code is below.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True, name="kick")

@has_permissions(kick_members=True)

async def kick(ctx, *, target: Member):

if target.server_permissions.administrator:

    await bot.say("Target is an admin")
else:
    try:
        await bot.kick(target)
        await bot.say('Kicked{}'.format(member.mention))
    except Exception:
        await bot.say("Something went wrong")

@kick.error
async def kick_error(error, ctx):

if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):

     await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "You do not have permissions")
elif isinstance(error, BadArgument):
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Could not identify target")
else:
    raise error
```

But the commands do kick the member but it doesn't says kicked (MEMBERNAME).
Instead it says 'something went wrong'. Also there are two commands Which work for my kick command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get why you try to except an `exception` if it isn't the case.

I deleted the `*` in `async def kick()` function as you only require the member not multiple arguments so it's kinda pointless to have it there and I also removed the `try` and `except` thing which in my opinion is useless in this case.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True, name="kick")

@has_permissions(kick_members=True)

async def kick(ctx, target: discord.Member=None):

    if target.server_permissions.administrator:

        await bot.say("Target is an admin")
    else:
        await bot.kick(target)
        await bot.say('Kicked{}'.format(target.mention))

@kick.error
async def kick_error(error, ctx):

if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):

     await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "You do not have permissions")
elif isinstance(error, BadArgument):
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Could not identify target")
else:
    raise error
```

If you want to check for example if the moderator or the person who uses the command is also putting a user in the command that should be kicked , you could do it with an `if` statement which would check if the `discord.Member` function is still `none` if yes it would output a message in chat. In this case I've put the message "You forgot the user"

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True, name="kick")

@has_permissions(kick_members=True)

async def kick(ctx, target: discord.Member=None):

    if target.server_permissions.administrator:

        await bot.say("Target is an admin")
    elif target = None:
        await bot.say("You forgot the user")
    else:
        await bot.kick(target)
        await bot.say('Kicked{}'.format(target.mention))

@kick.error
async def kick_error(error, ctx):

if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):

     await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "You do not have permissions")
elif isinstance(error, BadArgument):
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Could not identify target")
else:
    raise error
```